# How to add loading animation before load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a click refresh div. But i have one question how can i add loading animation in my code.

```
$('.refresh_div').live("click",function(){
    $('.content').load('present.php');
});
```

Comment: note, live() is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `loading` class while content is being loaded:

```
var d = $('.refresh_div');
d.live("click",function(){
    d.addClass('loading');
    $('.content').load('present.php', function () {
        d.removeClass('loading');
    });
});
```

Then just apply needed styles in CSS (e.g. icon, animation, etc).

Comment: Pavel - thanks for the info about the load function being asynchronous, I've upvoted your answer.